# Discord.JS Command Handler Sub-Folders

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, fs

I currently have a Discord.JS command handler that loads all commands in the command folder. However it is getting a bit messy now due to all the commands, therefore I have been trying to implement Sub-Folders. This would clean up the files inside the commands folder, organizing them into folder groups.

I currently have this code for loading the commands in the same folder.

But I am stuck on how I could go into each folder in the commands directory and load the commands.
If someone could help me, that would be appreciated.

```
const allCommands = fs.readdirSync('./commands');
for (const command of allCommands) {
    try {
        const loadedCommand = require(`./commands/${command}`);
        commands.set(loadedCommand.name, loadedCommand);
        
        for(const alias of loadedCommand.aliases || []) 
            commands.set(alias, { ...loadedCommand, alias: true });
        
        logger.info(`Loaded command ${loadedCommand.name} (${command})`);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(`Failed to load command ${command}. **Please report the following error:**`);
        logger.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move everything into its own function with the path as a parameter.
Every time you find a folder, call the function with the folder path.

```
(function readdir(path='./commands') {
    const allCommands = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (const command of allCommands) {
        if(fs.statSync(`${path}/${command}`).isDirectory()) {
            readdir(`${path}/${command}`);
            continue;
        }

        try {
            const loadedCommand = require(`${path}/${command}`);
            commands.set(loadedCommand.name, loadedCommand);
            
            for(const alias of loadedCommand.aliases || []) 
                commands.set(alias, { ...loadedCommand, alias: true });
            
            logger.info(`Loaded command ${loadedCommand.name} (${path}/${command})`);
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(`Failed to load command ${path}/${command}. **Please report the following error:**`);
            logger.error(error);
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I don't recommend importing this way. You might have better luck if you import each of your commands into a seperate javascript file then export each of your commands from there, it should make your controller level code much easier to read

Comment: python? the question is tagged javascript and discord.js

Comment: I don't know how I thought this was python but my answer still applies to JavaScript